# Poor Text Quality 1080P HD Monitor 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

My situation

I'm not proficient with Ubuntu or Linux. I'm a Windows convert. My computer tech knowledge is also novice. I'm running a NVIDIA GF119 on UBUNTU 12.04. Under Additional Drivers I have "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version 331-updates)" activated and currently in use.  I'm a student and I read hundreds of page of text out of ebooks everyday.

My issue

Text quality is blurry.  It's hard to tell the difference between i's and l's (infact I can't tell the difference as I just typed those two.)  also m's and n's often look the same.  I don't know what refresh rate I'm currently running, but my monitor is built to run 60 hz.  I tried xrandr -r 60 and got this.

> Rate 60.0 Hz not available for this size

I found another article on this, but the solution was over my head.

How can I get the text readable?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!  Okay I couldn't find settings>display>scale on my version.  However while looking for it I came across Universal Access.  When I went in and increased the size of text, it solved my resolution problem.  Thanks to everyone for contributing!!!!

[image]